# how to avoid row number in read_sql output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When I use pandas read_sql to read from mysql, it returns rows with row number as first column as given below. Is this possible to avoid row numbers?

[image]

Comment: That's the index column, set index to something else to remove that

Comment: Why?  Every pandas row needs a unique index.  That's what you're seeing.  You don't need to use it in your computations, and of course you don't need to print it.

Comment: @TimRoberts Technically, a Pandas index doesn't have to be unique.

Comment: not sure if you are referring to the pandas row index as the "first column". The values - 0, 1, 2, 3 are pandas row indices and not a column of the dataframe.

Comment: Thanks All. I need to export the rows into CSV to visualiser. So row numbers are not required. in the csv function of pandas, I have set index=False to avoid index being shown. and that worked. Thank you all for your help. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `False` as the second parameter to exclude indexing.

##### Example

```
df.to_csv('filename.csv', index = False, encoding='utf-8')
print(df)
```

or

```
df.toPandas().to_csv('filename.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
print(df)
```

Use this function to guide you

```
DataFrame.to_csv(self, path_or_buf=None, sep=', ', na_rep='', float_format=None, columns=None, header=True, index=True, index_label=None, mode='w', encoding=None, compression='infer', quoting=None, quotechar='"', line_terminator=None, chunksize=None, date_format=None, doublequote=True, escapechar=None, decimal='.')
```

You can read more about this here -> [Pandas DataFrame: to_csv() function](https://www.w3resource.com/pandas/dataframe/dataframe-to_csv.php)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks All. I need to export the rows into CSV to visualizer. So row numbers are not required. in the csv function of pandas, I have set index=False to avoid index being shown. and that worked. Thank you all for your help. Cheers

```
df.toPandas().to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```